# How to detect when innerHTML is complete

Tags: javascript

I've done quite a bit of searching for a solution to this problem but so far haven't found one that works cross browser.

What I need is a raw javascript function which will take an element and run a callback once the innerHTML has successfully been inserted into the dom.

e.g.

```
    var element = document.getElementById('example');
        element.innerHTML = newhtml;

    waitUntilReady(element, function(){
            //do stuff here...
    });
```

So just to summarize, I need to be able to check the contents of the element and fire a callback when innerHTML has completed.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/asynchronous-innerhtml/

Comment: What makes you think you need a callback?

Comment: @am not I am - Please see my comment below to Kolink's answer

Comment: Nope not exatcly, however this was a very interesting ready and i'd like to thank you for the link. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need for such a function. Assigning to `innerHTML` will do so immediately before continuing to run any scripts.

If you really need to delay execution (say to allow the browser to redraw), use `setTimeout` with a delay of `1` (or other short interval).

Comment: Ahh, if that is indeed the case then great.  But this still leaves me with my original issue. I am dynamically inserting a script straight after appending the html which attaches events to certain elements contained within the new html.  While this works fine on most browsers older IE 8 and below seem be returning that the element is null about 50% of the time.  My assumption was that this was because the newly inserted html was not always 'ready' when I was attempting to attache events to it.

Comment: Make sure the scripts are being added to the page somewhere after the `innerHTML` assignment and there's no reason for it to not work.

Comment: They are indeed.  Yet it still seems to have only a 50% success rate in older versions of IE.  I suppose the problem must lay elsewhere in my code and my assumption about the html not being 'ready' was incorrect.

Comment: I am doing something like: element.innerHTML = "<div style='width='100%;'></div>"; but on the next line element.children[0].offsetWidth is 0, I assume because it has not rendered yet. This is on latest Chrome. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: @pilavdzice - read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful

Comment: You may also have to get the element again, by just repeating the first line of the code, with the getElementById.

Comment: This is incorrect as of Chrome 76. When setting innerHTML and then calling getElementByID for an element inside the new markup, the result is undefined 50% of the time I've found.

Comment: @JudsonHudson Can you show an example of this happening?

Comment: > "There is no need for such a function. Assigning to innerHTML will do so immediately before continuing to run any scripts." That may be so, but the browser may not have rendered it. For instance, in my chat app, a large `div` update followed by a `scrolltobottom` fails to actually reach the bottom because the div isn't all that full (yet.) Waiting allows it to work properly; but a solution that actually finds out if the div is fully rendered is called for to address this circumstance.