# Detect when everything is loaded after change of innerHTML

Tags: javascript

I'm using this code to change the content of an div

```
mydiv.innerHTML = "html code with text and images";
```

Is there some events I can use to get a notification when everything is loaded? (no matter if there is no or many images )

I guess I could go through all child elements and addeventlisteners to them, but wish there is some other way.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me: do you want the event to be triggered when the contents of the `div` are loaded or when the whole page is loaded?

Comment: You need to detect when innerHTML is complete?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [assign event to div when it has loaded fully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160614/assign-event-to-div-when-it-has-loaded-fully)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect when innerHTML is complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11513392/how-to-detect-when-innerhtml-is-complete)

Comment: If you don't do it async you don't need to detect anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this, just to give you an idea in vanilla javascript

```js
var updateContent = function(element, content) {

    element.innerHTML = content;
    var images = element.querySelectorAll('img');
    var loadedItems = 0;
    var totalItems =  images.length;
    
    var loaded = function() {
        loadedItems++;
        
        console.log('loaded item: ' + loadedItems);

        if(loadedItems == totalItems) {
            element.classList.add('load-completed')
            console.log('finished loading all images');
        }
    };
    
    for(var i=0; i < totalItems; i++){
        if(images[i].complete) {
            loaded();
        } else {
          images[i].addEventListener('load', loaded);
          images[i].addEventListener('error', function() {
            console.log('error');
          });
        }
    }
}

updateContent(
     document.querySelector('.my-div'),
    '<h1>hello world<\h1><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/300">'
);
```

```css
.my-div {
   border:solid 5px orange;
}

.my-div img {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
}

.load-completed {
    border: dashed 5px green;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-div"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I guess I have to do it this way, I was just hoping there was some kind of event I could subscribe to, so I would be notified when its done. Somethin like the load event when the page has loaded, but for "dom changes"

Answer (score 0):

**Edit 2012** `live` The live method is deprecated as of **jQuery 1.7.0**.

The [.on() event](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is now recommended for attaching event handlers.

This replaces `.bind()`, `.delegate()`, and `.live()`.

See the docs: http://api.jquery.com/on/

*Original Answer*

i think **jQuery** `.live()` event might be what you're looking for.

try this

```
  mydiv.live('load', function () {
     //code here
 });
```